# Overloading templated class binary operator*

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, operator-overloading

I'm writing a 2D matrix template to learn templates and some C++11 features.

Wrote the following header:

```
template <class T, unsigned int Rows, unsigned int Columns>
class Matrix2D
{
private:
    array<array<T,Columns>, Rows> m_Matrix;

public:
    Matrix2D() {}

    array<T,Columns>& operator[](unsigned int row)       { return m_Matrix[row]; } ;
    const array<T,Columns>& operator[](unsigned int row) const { return m_Matrix[row]; } ;

    friend Matrix2D operator+ <> (const Matrix2D &lhs, const Matrix2D &rhs);
    friend Matrix2D operator* <> (const Matrix2D &lhs, const Matrix2D &rhs);
};
```

The `operator+` works fine - I have an implementation, it compiles, links, and stepped through with the debugger.

Problem is with `operator*`, for which I get the compilation error

```
1>...\matrix2d.h(18): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>...\matrix2d.h(19) : see reference to class template instantiation 'Matrix2D<T,Rows,Columns>' being compiled
```

There's no line of code trying to use the operator, so it's the definition itself which is wrong, I just don't understand why.

Can anyone help?

**EDIT**: (*added from comment*)

```
template <class T, unsigned int Rows, unsigned int Columns>
Matrix2D<T, Rows, Columns> operator+ (const Matrix2D<T, Rows, Columns> &lhs, const Matrix2D<T, Rows, Columns> &rhs)
{
    Matrix2D<T, Rows, Columns> addResult;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Rows; i++)
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < Columns; j++)
            addResult[i][j] = lhs[i][j] + rhs[i][j];
    return addResult;
}

template <class T, unsigned int Rows, unsigned int Columns>
Matrix2D<T, Rows, Columns> operator* (const Matrix2D<T, lRows, lColumns> &lhs, const Matrix2D<T, rRows, rColumns> &rhs)
{
    Matrix2D<T, lRows, rColumns> mulResult;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < lRows; i++)
        for(unsigned int j = 0; j < rColumns; j++)
            for (unsigned int k = 0; k < lColumns; k++)
                mulResult[i][k] += lhs[i][k] * rhs[k][j];
    return addResult;
}
```

Comment: What is the definition of `operator*`? Please, add it to the question. There is only the friend declaration in the question.

Comment: Compilation fails before reaching the definition, so I omitted it. Here it is, if it matters any

template <class T, unsigned int Rows, unsigned int Columns> Matrix2D<T, Rows, Columns>
 operator* (const Matrix2D<T, lRows, lColumns> &lhs, const Matrix2D<T, rRows, rColumns> &rhs)
{
 Matrix2D<T, lRows, rColumns> mulResult;
 
 for(unsigned int i = 0; i < lRows;    i++)
 for(unsigned int j = 0; j < rColumns; j++)
  for (unsigned int k = 0; k < lColumns; k++)
   mulResult[i][k] += lhs[i][k] * rhs[k][j];

 return addResult;
}

Comment: @UriRaz: you may edit your question instead of adding implementation in comment.

Comment: Could you post a complete example showing both the working `operator+` and non-compilable `operator*`? In general, to friend a full specialization of some template (such as these operators), it (the template you're specializing) needs to be declared prior to this point.

Comment: Considering your posted header file contains only 15 lines, yet the compiler is complaining about something on lines 18 and 19, I'd say you probably need to show us "the rest of the story"...

Comment: This is the code for operator+

template <class T, unsigned int Rows, unsigned int Columns> Matrix2D<T, Rows, Columns>
 operator* (const Matrix2D<T, Rows, Columns> &lhs, const Matrix2D<T, Rows, Columns> &rhs)
{
 Matrix2D<T, Rows, Columns> addResult;
 
 for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Rows;    i++)
 for (unsigned int j = 0; j < Columns; j++)
  addResult[i][j] = lhs[i][j] + rhs[i][j];

 return addResult;
}

Comment: This is main's code

#include "Matrix2D.h"


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 Matrix2D<float,2,2> Matrix1, Matrix2, Matrix3;

 Matrix1[0][0] = 1.0;
 Matrix1[0][1] = 2.0;
 Matrix1[1][0] = 3.0;
 Matrix1[1][1] = 4.0;

 Matrix2[0][0] = 4.0;
 Matrix2[0][1] = 3.0;
 Matrix2[1][0] = 2.0;
 Matrix2[1][1] = 1.0;

 return 0;
}

Comment: Please stop putting code into comments. **EDIT** the question instead, see the "edit" button under the tags.

Comment: Starting with 'The operator+ works fine': erase the existing operator* - copy the operator+ - change + to * - alter it

Comment: @DieterLücking That's not the solution, GCC generates a special warning for `operator*` in the OPs case. Clang, BTW, does not do that.

Comment: OP's problem is the signature of `operator *` which take different size of matrices.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot friend a specialization of an undeclared template function. Of course, declaring the operators before defining the class template will require you to forward declare it as well:

```
template <class T, unsigned int Rows, unsigned int Columns>
class Matrix2D;

template <class T, unsigned int Rows, unsigned int Columns>
Matrix2D<T, Rows, Columns>
operator+ (const Matrix2D<T, Rows, Columns> &lhs, const Matrix2D<T, Rows, Columns> &rhs);

template <class T, unsigned int Rows, unsigned int Columns>
Matrix2D<T, Rows, Columns>
operator* (const Matrix2D<T, Rows, Columns> &lhs, const Matrix2D<T, Rows, Columns> &rhs);

template <class T, unsigned int Rows, unsigned int Columns>
class Matrix2D
{
private:
    array<array<T,Columns>, Rows> m_Matrix;

public:
    Matrix2D() {}

    array<T,Columns>& operator[](unsigned int row)       { return m_Matrix[row]; }
    const array<T,Columns>& operator[](unsigned int row) const { return m_Matrix[row]; }

    friend Matrix2D operator+ <> (const Matrix2D &lhs, const Matrix2D &rhs);
    friend Matrix2D operator* <> (const Matrix2D &lhs, const Matrix2D &rhs);
};
```

alternatively, you could take the easy way and define separate operator functions for each specialization of `Matrix2D`:

```
template <class T, unsigned int Rows, unsigned int Columns>
class Matrix2D
{
private:
    array<array<T,Columns>, Rows> m_Matrix;

public:
    Matrix2D() {}

    array<T,Columns>& operator[](unsigned int row)       { return m_Matrix[row]; }
    const array<T,Columns>& operator[](unsigned int row) const { return m_Matrix[row]; }

    friend Matrix2D operator+ (const Matrix2D &lhs, const Matrix2D &rhs) {
        // do stuff that adds.
    }
    friend Matrix2D operator* (const Matrix2D &lhs, const Matrix2D &rhs) {
        // do stuff that multiplies.
    }
};
```

which I would probably use for the simpler overall syntax.

EDIT: Proper multiplication of non-square matrices means that the `operator*` function would in fact need to be friends of three different specializations of `Matrix2D`: the type of the left operand, right operand, and result. I think the first approach herein would become untenable. You should either friend all specializations of `operator*`:

```
template <class T, unsigned int Rows, unsigned int Columns>
class Matrix2D
{
  // ...

  template <typename U, typename V, unsigned Rows, unsigned Common, unsigned Columns>
  friend Matrix2D<decltype(std::declval<U>()+std::declval<V>()), Rows, Columns>
  operator * (const Matrix2D<U, Rows, Common>&,
              const Matrix2D<V, Common, Columns>&);

};
```

or simply make the data public (probably the best approach for a "collection-of-data" class anyhow).

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
template <class T, unsigned int Rows, unsigned int Columns>
class Matrix2D
{
    // ...
    friend Matrix2D operator* <> (const Matrix2D &lhs, const Matrix2D &rhs);
};
```

`Matrix2D` refer in fact to `Matrix2D<T, Rows, Columns>` .

And your `operator *` should be

```
template <T, unsigned Rows1, unsigned int Common, unsigned int Column>
Matrix2D<T, Row1, Column> operator* (const Matrix2D<T, Row1, Common>& lhs, const Matrix2D<T, Common, Column>& rhs);
```